# Question about the performance of a home-brewed mutable string object in Python

Tags: python, performance, memory-management, immutability, python-3.7

I'm creating a simple unix console text scroller and my approach is to continually append a deque with its max len set to the screen width. Everytime I clear the console and append a new character to the deque, I am joining (''.join(deque)) the contents of the deque into a string to print to the console. I know that everytime I do this I am creating a new object. The text files I am feeding into the scroller are huge and I'm wondering if the constant creation of string objects in this manner isn't grossly inefficient when it comes to memory. I thought about using StringIO, but everytime I call getvalue() it also creates a new object. It seems that anyway I approached it, printing to the console would create a new object with a unique id. So I created a simple MutableString class. Using the **str**() method, I can print to the console and the class object appears to only have two ids associated with it. One for the class object itself and one for the object created when **str**() is called by print(). My question is: is this approach actually more efficient than calling ''.join(deque) as I was doing? Is the simple class I created actually mutable and therefore saving resources? If not, what might be a computationally inexpensive way to add characters to a string? Thanks for your time and attention!

```
from collections import deque

class MutableString:

    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = deque(string)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f'mutable_string.MutableString({self.__str__()})'


    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join(self.string)


    def __add__(self, other):
        self.string.append(other)
```

Comment: This _may_ be a good question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com since your code works but you're trying to improve efficiency

Comment: Wait, how is this different from your other approach? You are still calling `''.join(self.string)`, which again, makes a new string object. Your class isn't immutable, and you even call it "mutable". Did you mean "Is the simple class I created actually **mutable** and therefore saving resources?" Well, it *is* mutable, but I don't see how it is saving resources. That isn't a logical implication of mutability/immutability

Comment: I meant mutable. Yes, it is calling ''.join() each time I print, but the object id remains the same even though the sting itself changes. I'm not talking about the class id, I mean printing the str() has a unique id and this id remains the same. So, I am trying to understand what;s actually happening. Is it creating a new string and discarding the old or is it returing the same object changed?